# "Constant expressions" prior to C++11

Tags: c++, c++03, c++98, compile-time-constant, constant-expression

The `constexpr` keyword was introduced in C++11, as (I think) was the corresponding idea of "constant expressions." However, this concept was implicitly present in C++98/c++03, since array declarations require a constant expression:

```
// valid:
int a[sizeof(int)];
int b[3+7];
int c[13/4];
const int n = 3;
int d[n];
// invalid:
int m = 4;
int e[m];
```

There are other "constant expressions", i.e., expressions that can be (and/or must be) evaluated at compile-time; one example is template arguments.

For pre-C++11, do the following exist, either in the C++98/03 standards or elsewhere?

- A complete list of syntactic constructs requiring constant expressions (e.g. array declarations and template instantiations)
- The rules governing such constant expressions (presumably this would just be a mapping from the items in the above list to their definitions in the standard)

Comment: Wait a minute!:  "array declarations require a *constant* expression"?  Why do you say that?

Comment: @wallyk Because it’s true.

Comment: @KonradRudolph the gift of compiler extensions, it is amazing how many C++ developers do not know this.

Comment: @wallyk Some compilers will allow a variable sized array on the stack, but will usually emit a warning.

Comment: @MoreAxes usually it requires the proper flag to receive a warning, for `gcc` and `clang` that would be `-pedantic`.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Indeed! As I was putting together those examples I was momentarily baffled when I found that I could compile `int e[m];` without warning or error (using `g++`).

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I was taught to use all of those except `-Wconversion`, but I have a bad habit of not using them when I'm just trying to quickly check some C++ feature or other.

Comment: I edited my answer a bit, I think for the better, let me know if you feel like I left anything out.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Thanks. Sorry, I've had a busy weekend and haven't had a chance to read it carefully yet, but I expect that when I do I'll accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) and *constant expressions* are related in that *constexpr* tells us that a variable or function can be used where a *constant expression* can be used. This is what cppreference tell us:

> The constexpr specifier declares that it is possible to evaluate the
>   value of the function or variable at compile time. Such variables and
>   functions can then be used where only compile time constant
>   expressions are allowed.

*Constant expresions* were present before C++11 and the rules governing constant expressions pre C++11 are covered in the same place in the [C++03 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1804.pdf)(*this is the earliest public draft available closest to C++03*)<sup>1</sup> as the [draft C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) which is section `5.19` *Constant expressions*, cppreference has a good summary on this topic in [Constant expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression) page but it is geared toward C++11 and C++14 and it hard to tell what applies pre C++11.

The standard pre C++11 lists where a constant expression is required, in first paragraph of `5.19` and it looks complete:

> In several places, C++ requires expressions that evaluate to an
>   integral or enumeration constant: as array bounds (8.3.4,
>   5.3.4), as case expressions (6.4.2), as bit-field lengths (9.6), as enumerator initializers (7.2), as static member initializers (9.4.2),
>   and as integral or enumeration non-type template arguments (14.3).

the rest of paragraph *1* says:

> An integral constant-expression can involve only literals of
>   arithmetic types (2.13, 3.9.1), enumerators, non-volatile const
>   variables or static data members of integral or enumeration types
>   initialized with constant expressions (8.5), non-type template
>   parameters of integral or enumeration types, and sizeof expressions.
>   Floating literals (2.13.3) can appear only if they are cast to
>   integral or enumeration types. Only type conversions to integral or
>   enumeration types can be used. In particular, except in sizeof
>   expressions, functions, class objects, pointers, or references shall
>   not be used, and assignment, increment, decrement, function-call, or
>   comma operators shall not be used.

and is followed by `5` more paragraphs that list further requirements.

In C++11 there is a list of where constant expressions can be used in paragraph *3* but it does not clarify where they are required. You probably have to search for the term *constant expression* to find all the places where it is required and usually there will be a phrase similar to:

> shall be a constant expression

The *shall* being the important term since violating a *shall* requirement makes the program ill-formed.

Alternatively you can use `Annex A` *Grammar summary* and search for *constant-expression* and that should cover all the places in the grammar where a *constant expression* is required, for example:

```
enumerator = constant-expression
```

---

Footnote:

1. This [answer to Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4653479/1708801) has a complete list of the draft standards. Unfortunately the closest that is available to the public is from early `2005`. The earlier versions require authentication. As far as I know section `5.19` did not change much.

Comment: The draft standard you link to is from 2005...is that really for `C++03`?

Comment: @KyleStrand it is earliest public draft standard available, you can find a complete list of the draft available to all [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents).