# Is a constexpr more "constant" than const?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, immutability, constexpr

*The C++ Programming Language Fourth Edition - Bjarne Stroustrup: (emphasis mine)*

***2.2.3. Constants***

> In a few places, constant expressions are required by language rules
>   (e.g., array bounds (§2.2.5, §7.3), case labels (§2.2.4, §9.4.2), some
>   template arguments (§25.2), and constants declared using constexpr).
>   In other cases, compile-time evaluation is important for performance.
>   ***Independently of performance issues, the notion of immutability (of an object with an unchangeable state) is an important design concern
>   (§10.4).***

It seems that Stroustrup is suggesting here that `constexpr` ensures immutability of an object better than a traditional `const` declaration. Is this correct? Are there ways in which `constexpr` can be more secure/less volatile than `const`, or does Stroustrup simply mean that since there are ways to use `constexpr` that are not supported with `const` (see **[Is constexpr really needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016771/is-constexpr-really-needed)**), in those cases immutability can be ensured using `constexpr`?

Comment: Related to [“Constant expressions” prior to C++11](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26024942/1708801)

Comment: I can't find my copy of the book to check the context, but since constexpr still does not guarantee immutability I would be surprised if that's what he's suggesting. From your short quote it looks to me like he's just saying immutability is important, not that constexpr is better for achieving that than const, or vice versa.

Comment: @JonathanWakely - Perhaps you are right, it's just thrown in there since the general subject is what he calls _immutability_. I am putting the whole paragraph up there now - it is a summation of the material on `constexpr`,so I understood there was something special about `constexpr`, like the other points mentioned there, but maybe not.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I think what makes it ambiguous is the way the sections are cited in specific statements, they seem to imply what the OP is asking about. I agree I don't believe he is suggesting that either but after reading it several times it is not the most clear statement even with the whole context.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

He states in the beginning of the section:

> C++ supports two notions of immutability

and he lists *const* and *constexpr*, I don't believe he is attempting to say that *constexpr* ensures immutability better than *const* they just have different features, although I admit the fact the sentence cites section `10.4` *Constant Expressions*  does seem to imply that, that interpretation is inconsistent with the rest of the text.

A variable that is `const` is immutable in that scope but may not be `const` in the larger scope(*for example a const reference parameter to a function*) and that is perhaps a subtle distinction he is attempting to make, he says that `const`:

> is used primarily to specify interfaces

whereas `constexpr`:

> This is used primarily to specify constants, to allow placement of data in read-only memory

Any variable that is `constexpr` should be evaluated at compile time and thus usable where constant expressions are required whereas a variable that is passed as `const` to a function does not have to be `const` outside that scope.

Sure you can cast away *constness* using `const_cast` but attempting to modify a `const` object is undefined behavior and so it is no less immutable than `constexpr` in that sense, from the [draft C++11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) section `7.1.6.1` *The cv-qualifiers*:

> any attempt to modify a const object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior

Jonathan Wakely notes that a *constexpr* variable like *const* variables can have a [mutable member](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1405) but that member can not be used in a constant expression.

Note that a *constexpr* variable is also *const*, from the draft C++11 standard section `7.1.5` *The constexpr specifier*:

> A constexpr specifier used in an object declaration declares the
>   object as const.

Comment: _He clearly states in the beginning of the section.._ Yes, understood. That's all part of the question: How do you modify the value of `myConst` in the declaration: `const int myConst=999`? The compiler enforces `const`. Maybe by subverting it with a pointer? Would that be impossible with `constexpr`? Is there something "more immutable" about `constexpr` I'm not sure I understand this answer, except in the case of variable passed as `const` into functions so they can't be modified in the function.

Comment: _"an object that is const is immutable in that scope but may not be const in the larger scope"_ technically an object is either const or not, period. A non-const object might be used through a "const access path" (e.g. through a const pointer), but the object itself is still non-const. And immutable doesn't just mean "doesn't change right now, but might change later".

Comment: @JonathanWakely that is what I get for writing that before I go to sleep, fixed.

Comment: As MikeMB's answer shows, a variable declared constexpr can still have mutable members, so is not truly a compile-time constant.

Comment: @JonathanWakely that is an interesting edge case, I reworded to be less absolute on that point.

Answer (score 5):

`const` dosn't ensure bitwise constness, e.g. as classes can have mutable members (typical example would be a private mutex for internal synchronization) and you can `const_cast` away the constness from a pointer.

`constexpr` declares a constant variable or function that can be calculated at compile time, which implies some restrictions on what the object can be, but I believe, the keyword itself doesn't provide any additional guarantees during runtime compared to `const`. 
See also [this](http://compgroups.net/comp.std.c++/defect-report-constexpr-and-mutable-members-of-l/2126042) discussion.

Comment: An object declared with constexpr can still have mutable members, even after the resolution of the issue Richard Smith raised ([DR 1405](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1405)) it just can't be used in a constant expression. So you're right that means constexpr still doesn't guarantee immutability. And you can `const_cast` away the constness of something declared `constexpr` (but trying to modify it is still undefined, just like a variable declared `const`)

Comment: Thats what I meant with "the keyword itself doesn't provide any additional guarantees during runtime compared to const". Do you want to say, I should remove the link?. I added it, because it was the first source I found, which explicitly stated that `constexpr` objects can have mutable members, thus supporting my point of "`constexpr` not beeing more constant than `const`"

Comment: I think it's useful to keep it

Comment: What remains unclear to me is, whether your comment was meant to support or correct my answer.

Comment: I was trying to support it with extra detail ... but you're right I wasn't very clear, sorry!