# constexpr const char * vs constexpr const char[]

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr

The "first attempt" doesn't compile while the second does. Why? What's the difference?

**First attempt:**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    constexpr const char text2[] = "hello";
    constexpr const char * b = &text2[4];  // error: '& text2[4]' is not a constant expression
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

**Second attempt:**

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
constexpr const char * text1 = "hello";
constexpr const char * a = &text1[4];
std::cout << a << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

I compile with (g++ version 4.9.2)

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o main *.cpp
```

which gives following error

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:7:40: error: '& text2[4]' is not a constant expression constexpr const char * b = &text2[4];  // error: '& text2[4]' is not a constant expression
```

Comment: I like how you named your variable text2 in the first attempt and test1 in the second attempt.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the draft C++11 standard section `5.19` *[expr.const]* we can see an [address constant expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression#Address_constant_expression) is (*emphasis mine gong forward*):

> [...] a prvalue core constant expression
>   of **pointer type that evaluates to the address of an object with
>   static storage duration**, to the address of a function, or to a null
>   pointer value, or a prvalue core constant expression of type
>   std::nullptr_t.

In your first case although `"hello"` is a string literal which has static storage duration. It is copied into an array `text2` which does not have static storage duration.

While in your second case `text1` is a pointer to a [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) which has static storage duration.

Changing your first example to make `text2` static (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/vGxTxgwXB9ey87aW)*):

```
constexpr char static text2[] = "hello";
               ^^^^^^
```

we no longer get an error.

We can see a string literal has static storage duration from section `2.14.5` *[lex.string]*:

> Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred
>   to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal has type “array
>   of n const char”, where n is the size of the string as defined below,
>   and has static storage duration (3.7).

Comment: Does `const` make a `constexpr` more constant?

Comment: @black no, they have [different roles](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27850923/1708801) for `text2` it is not needed but for the pointers it is.

Comment: Had to think about it, might as well write it out: in the case of `text2`, the array gets initialized from the string literal, but the array is a per-instance copy of the string, so taking the address of its fifth element points to a different location in every instance and that is not a constant expression. in the case of `text1`, the string literal is placed in static space and `text1` is set to the same address in every instance of the class, so taking the address of the fifth element points to the same location in every instance and that is a constant expression.

Comment: @BlairHoughton that is a good point, I actually realized later on that pointing that out may be helpful. Thank you for making the comment.