# Is it possible to initialise a character array with a conditionally selected string literal?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, string-literals

I know it's perfectly possible to initialise a `char` array with a string literal:

```
char arr[] = "foo";
```

C++11 8.5.2/1 says so:

> A `char` array (whether plain `char`, `signed char`, or `unsigned char`), `char16_t` array, `char32_t` array, or
>   `wchar_t` array can be initialized by a narrow character literal, `char16_t` string literal, `char32_t` string
>   literal, or wide string literal, respectively, or by an appropriately-typed string literal enclosed in braces.
>   Successive characters of the value of the string literal initialize the elements of the array. ...

However, can you do the same with *two* string literals in a conditional expression? For example like this:

```
char arr[] = MY_BOOLEAN_MACRO() ? "foo" : "bar";
```

(Where `MY_BOOLEAN_MACRO()` expands to a `1` or `0`).

The relevant parts of C++11 5.16 (Conditional operator) are as follows:

> 1 ... The first expression is contextually converted to `bool` (Clause 4).
>   It is evaluated and if it is `true`, the result of the conditional expression is the value of the second expression,
>   otherwise that of the third expression. ...
>
> 4 If the second and third operands are glvalues of the same value category and have the same type, the result
>   is of that type and value category and it is a bit-field if the second or the third operand is a bit-field, or if
>   both are bit-fields.

Notice that the literals are of the same length and thus they're both lvalues of type `const char[4]`.

[GCC one ideone](http://ideone.com/eih2Jm) accepts the construct. But from reading the standard, I am simply not sure whether it's legal or not. Does anyone have better insight?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the other hand `clang` does not accept such code (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/jTTGMnBzfy1t9mFV)*) and I believe `clang` is correct on this (*[MSVC also rejects this code](http://rextester.com/NQECUL1379)* ).

A *string literal* is defined by the grammar in section `2.14.5`:

```
string-literal:
    encoding-prefixopt" s-char-sequenceopt"
    encoding-prefixoptR raw-string
```

and the first paragraph from this section says (*emphasis mine*):

> A string literal **is a sequence of characters** (as defined in 2.14.3)
>   **surrounded by double quotes**, optionally prefixed by R, u8, u8R, u, uR,
>   U, UR, L, or LR, as in "...", R"(...)", u8"...", u8R"**(...)**",
>   u"...", uR"*˜(...)*˜", U"...", UR"zzz(...)zzz", L"...", or LR"(...)",
>   respectively

and it further says that the type of a narrow string literal is:

> “array of n const char”,

as well as:

> has static storage duration

but an *“array of n const char”,* with static storage duration is not a *string literal* since it does not fit the grammar nor does it fit paragraph `1`.

We can make this fail on `gcc` if we use a non-constant expression (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/gEV3ImIU5KBYa5ee)*):

```
bool x = true ;
char arr[] = x ? "foo" : "bar";
```

which means it is probably an extension, but it is non-conforming since it does not produce a warning in [strict conformance mode](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html) i.e. using `-std=c++11 -pedantic`. From section `1.4` *[intro.compliance]*:

> [...]Implementations are required to diagnose programs that use such
>   extensions that are ill-formed according to this International
>   Standard. Having done so, however, they can compile and execute such
>   programs.

Comment: Agree, 8.5.2/1 seems pretty clear that it is *string literal* and not *some expression which evaluates to a string literal*. (even if you consider the ternary operator as evaluating to a string literal in this case).

Answer (score 3):

This works in GCC *in C++11 or newer* because the literals you're providing are deterministic during compile time (eg, they are `constexpr`). Since the compiler can figure out which one is true, it is allowed to figure out which one to use.

To remove the `constexpr` ability, try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    bool _bool = rand();
    char arr[] = (_bool) ? "asdf" : "ffff";

    std::cout << arr << std::endl;
}
```

GCC then errors out with:

```
g++ test.cpp -std=c++11
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:6:34: error: initializer fails to determine size of ‘arr’
  char arr[] = (_bool) ? "asdf" : "ffff";
                                  ^
test.cpp:6:34: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
```

I don't know the standard's text definition well enough to know where or why this is valid, but I *feel* that it *is* valid.

For further reading on `constexpr` and how it can impact compilability, see [the answer by @ShafikYaghmour in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26025026/1708801).

Comment: Note that *constant expression* and *constexpr* are related but not the same, I cover that to some degree [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26025026/1708801) so `gcc` is treating it as a constant expression.

Comment: True, I can see that there's a distinction. But it's a fine point and I don't think that the difference applies in c++11 and beyond... unless you can show that it does?

Comment: It is purely informative, hopefully you find it helpful. I would just note that since the question is tagged language-lawyer people will tend to be more picky about details.